# Design-time size of Label (Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I refer to the Visual Studio design view. When adding a label using the full .NET framework, `System.Windows.Forms.Label` controls have an `AutoSize` property set to True by default. If I drop a `Label` control onto a form, the default font is "Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt, Regular" and the height of the control is 20. Change the font to (say) "Tahoma, 14pt, Bold" and the height automatically changes to 23. Fine.

But in the CF (Compact-Framework), `Label` controls do not have the `AutoSize` property. When I change the font as described above the height of the `Label` does not change (staying at 20) and some of the text is chopped off).

My question is: Short of opening a full .NET project and testing my font selection, is there a way to know what height to set my `Label` at design-time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the graphics object for to measure the height of the string, for example in `Paint` event or `OnPaint` method:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
float lineHeight = g.MeasureString(this.Text, this.Font).Height;
```

it can be used in inherited label. for example you can override `OnPaint` method or somewhere else and do this, then it will run in design-time.

More resources:

- Base on [Font height in compact framework](https://learningwindowsmobile.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/font-height-in-compact-framework/)
- Aslo you can take a look at [Multi-Line Graphics.MeasureString on .Net CF](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2007/12/multi-line-graphicsmeasurestring.html) that uses `DrawText` from `coredll.dll`.

Comment: That's great (and something I use already) but that is a runtime check. My question is about the design-time size of the label (ie. the properties of the control in the Visual Studio designer).

Comment: @AlainD I think it can be used in inherited label. for example you can override `OnPaint` method and do this. then it will run in design-time.

Comment: @AlainD Aslo you can take a look at [Multi-Line Graphics.MeasureString on .Net CF](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2007/12/multi-line-graphicsmeasurestring.html)

Comment: Your answer is excellent...but for a different question! My question relates to how you might determine the size of the label at design-time (ie. before compiling and running the application). The Visual Studio Designer simply doesn't resize the label when you change the text when targeting CF applications, but does when targeting full .NET applications.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)